# Norm of the inverse of a tridiagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, inverse

Let's take a tridiagonal matrix (in general not Toeplitz, nor symmetric)

$$L=\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & -b_1 & & & \\ -c_1 & a_2 & -b_2 \\ & -c_2 & \ddots & \ddots\\
& & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$$

and suppose that it's an M-matrix, diagonally dominant, with $a_i,b_i,c_i>0$, $a_i\ge c_{i-1}+ b_i$, ($c_0=b_n=0$) and such that there exists at least an index $i$ with $a_i> c_{i-1}+ b_i$.

I'm interested in an upper bound for the infinity norm of the inverse.

I already know that if $0<\gamma\le a_i-c_{i-1}- b_i$ for all indexes, then
$$\|L^{-1}\|_{\infty}\le \gamma^{-1}$$
and, more in general, if $w\ge 0$ and $Lw\ge \gamma e$, then
$$\|L^{-1}\|_{\infty}\le \gamma^{-1}\|w\|_{\infty}$$

I also know that for the particular matrix with $a_i=2, b_i=c_i=1$, we have
$$\|L^{-1}\|_{\infty}\le \frac{(n+1)^2}{8}$$

Is there some general result of this kind?
And if the matrix is Toeplitz, there's a rule for the dependence of such a bound to $n^k$ for some $k$?

Note: This [Link](http://www.mat.uc.pt/preprints/ps/p0516.pdf) may be useful.

Comment: @epimorphic I hope you get to read this. I was referring to the discrete version of the maximum principle, applicable on matrices, that gives indeed useful bounds to the norm.

Comment: Apologies if that's the case. I'm trying to gradually clean up the tag since it is so often mistakenly used. The tag definition specifies PDE and complex analysis, though I do try to make exceptions for similarly-named theorems in other fields to the extent that I'm aware. Could you provide a reference for this discrete maximum principle?

Comment: @epimorphic It's often used to determine the stability of numerical methods for computing PDE. Here an example with the standard Laplacian Matrix. 
https://books.google.it/books?id=chinLsuVsYsC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=numerical+stability+pde+%22maximum+principle%22&source=bl&ots=FPQ8vPZmMi&sig=DeyZguEyW8opQWm5G1PnowHWWe4&hl=it&sa=X&ei=1JJ0VZnFDOHmyQODl4CoBw&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=numerical%20stability%20pde%20%22maximum%20principle%22&f=false
When I find some other reference, I'll let you know